# Is hidden backlink blackhat SEO?

Tags: seo, search-engines, backlinks

See below link. It will create a huge backlink for me if I put it on dynamically generated blog posts. Is it a blackhat SEO strategy?

`<a href="http://example.com" style="display: none;">Example</a>`

Comment: I am not sure what value a hidden link would have if it is not for search engines. Do not try and manipulate anything search or SEO. There are no tricks or magic buttons to push in just the right sequence. Do honest work in creating a site that people love and allow the organic links to manifest. You can create some backlinks too of course, but blogs and forums are of little value these days because of all the previous abuses. Go with honest page to page, topic to topic links just like they were always meant to be and you will do fine. Trust me on that one.

Comment: Just ensure you have some kind of trigger using jquery or css so the link can become visible and usable then your ok.

Answer (score 4):

It's a blackhat SEO technique if you want to manipulate search engines rankings. It can be considered as OK if the links are hidden for better user experience.

See [this page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353?hl=en) on Google support for more information.

Indeed, a hidden link is not seen by visitors instead of search engines bots. It can be considered as [cloaking](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en) and it's punished by search engines in general.

Comment: But, one person from my country who have 253000 + backlink. For that reason, I/ none of competitor can't cross him anyway for few keywords. :(

Comment: Until Google finds these backlinks and decides to penalize the site of this person... Blackhat techniques are not penalized immediately. It always takes time but when Google finds the bad practice, he penalized severely. Keep your backlinks profile clean and you insure your site rnakings in the long term.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is both Yes and No. First lets start with possible reasons for using a hidden link:

1. You're trying to abuse search networks, botpush, stuff, or sneak in data
2. You're using JS to unhide it somehow client side like in an accordion
3. You're using it like a honeypot and its well protected with nofollow/robots.txt
4. Neither of these, its just temp commented out because you're still working on it

So it seems like your example falls into the first of the list, trying to abuse or sneak in data. Furthermore, it seems like you know you're doing something wrong or the environment includes shadyness. Otherwise there would be no point in hiding it, right?

In the end, a hidden link is a hidden link. Its not the link's fault if you abuse it with blackhat methods. So to answer your question:

*Hidden links are whitehat SEO until you abuse them. If you choose to abuse by operating a questionable environment, then yes hidden links are blackhat SEO.*